# Buscar en array un carácter según un índice en específico Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo un 3 en raya, se que no es nada óptimo el código pero recién estoy aprendiendo Javascript. El tema es que necesito buscar la cadena de texto "-" dentro de un array según el índice que me de una función, la cual, me da un número random. El problema esta en esta línea,

(GuardarPosiciones.includes("-",numRandom)). si el usuario pone una X la maquina lo machaca y pone una O encima.

```
function pintaMaquina (){
    maquina = "o";
    alert("Esta pintando la maquina...");

    var numRandom = generarNumRandom();
    alert("numRandom " + numRandom );
    
    if (GuardarPosiciones.includes("-",numRandom)) { //Si en la posicion del numero random hay una - pintamos encima
        alert("no existe ningun valor");
        pintarO(numRandom);
        GuardarPosiciones.splice(numRandom,0,maquina);
        alert(GuardarPosiciones);
    } else {
        alert("Si que existe un valor");
        pintaMaquina();
    } 

}
```

```js
    
const GuardarPosiciones = new Array(9);
var n1 = "-";
var n2 = "-";
var n3 = "-";
var n4 = "-";
var n5 = "o";
var n6 = "-";
var n7 = "-";
var n8 = "-";
var n9 = "-";
var agregarPosiciones;

function vaciarTexto(){
    //Al clicar se pone automaticamente una x y se cambia el fondo en rojo
    var selected = document.activeElement;

    if (selected.id == "casilla1") {
        document.getElementById("casilla1").value ="x";
        document.getElementById("casilla1").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
        document.getElementById("casilla1").disabled = true;
    } else if (selected.id == "casilla2") {
        document.getElementById("casilla2").value ="x";  
        document.getElementById("casilla2").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
        document.getElementById("casilla2").disabled = true;
    } else if (selected.id == "casilla3") {
        document.getElementById("casilla3").value ="x";
        document.getElementById("casilla3").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
        document.getElementById("casilla3").disabled = true;
    } else if (selected.id == "casilla4") {
        document.getElementById("casilla4").value ="x";  
        document.getElementById("casilla4").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
        document.getElementById("casilla4").disabled = true;
    } else if (selected.id == "casilla5") {
        document.getElementById("casilla5").value ="x";
        document.getElementById("casilla5").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
        document.getElementById("casilla5").disabled = true;
    } else if (selected.id == "casilla6") {
        document.getElementById("casilla6").value ="x";  
        document.getElementById("casilla6").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
        document.getElementById("casilla6").disabled = true;
    } else if (selected.id == "casilla7") {
        document.getElementById("casilla7").value ="x";
        document.getElementById("casilla7").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
        document.getElementById("casilla7").disabled = true;
    } else if (selected.id == "casilla8") {
        document.getElementById("casilla8").value ="x";  
        document.getElementById("casilla8").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
        document.getElementById("casilla8").disabled = true;
    } else if (selected.id == "casilla9") {
        document.getElementById("casilla9").value ="x";
        document.getElementById("casilla9").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
        document.getElementById("casilla9").disabled = true;
    } 

}

function desactivarCasillas(){
    //desabilitamos todas las casillas al usuario meter una x
    document.getElementById("casilla1").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("casilla2").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("casilla3").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("casilla4").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("casilla5").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("casilla6").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("casilla7").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("casilla8").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("casilla9").disabled = true;     
}

function activarCasillas(){
    //habilitamos todas las casillas al inicio
    document.getElementById("casilla1").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("casilla2").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("casilla3").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("casilla4").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("casilla5").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("casilla6").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("casilla7").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("casilla8").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("casilla9").disabled = false;     
}

function ingresar_datos() {
    //ingresamos los datos recogidos después de habilitar las casillas
    n1 = document.getElementById('casilla1').value;
    n2 = document.getElementById('casilla2').value;
    n3 = document.getElementById('casilla3').value;
    n4 = document.getElementById('casilla4').value;
    n5 = document.getElementById('casilla5').value;
    n6 = document.getElementById('casilla6').value;
    n7 = document.getElementById('casilla7').value;
    n8 = document.getElementById('casilla8').value;
    n9 = document.getElementById('casilla9').value;
    agregarPosiciones = GuardarPosiciones.push(n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9);
    console.table(GuardarPosiciones);
}

function pintarO(casilla){
    //ponemos una o en el numero random que elija la máquina
    switch (casilla) {
        case 9:
        casilla1.value ="o";
        casilla1.style.backgroundColor = "#00BDFF";
        document.getElementById("casilla1").disabled = true;
        break;

        case 10:
        casilla2.value ="o";  
        casilla2.style.backgroundColor = "#00BDFF";
        document.getElementById("casilla2").disabled = true;
        break;

        case 11:
        casilla3.value ="o";
        casilla3.style.backgroundColor = "#00BDFF";
        document.getElementById("casilla3").disabled = true;
        break;

        case 12:
        casilla4.value ="o";  
        casilla4.style.backgroundColor = "#00BDFF";
        document.getElementById("casilla4").disabled = true;
        break;

        case 13:
        casilla5.value ="o";
        casilla5.style.backgroundColor = "#00BDFF";
        document.getElementById("casilla5").disabled = true;
        break;

        case 14:
        casilla6.value ="o";  
        casilla6.style.backgroundColor = "#00BDFF";
        document.getElementById("casilla6").disabled = true;
        break;

        case 15:
        casilla7.value ="o";
        casilla7.style.backgroundColor = "#00BDFF";
        document.getElementById("casilla7").disabled = true;
        break;

        case 16:
        casilla8.value ="o";  
        casilla8.style.backgroundColor = "#00BDFF";
        document.getElementById("casilla8").disabled = true;
        break;

        case 17:
        casilla9.value ="o";
        casilla9.style.backgroundColor = "#00BDFF";
        document.getElementById("casilla9").disabled = true;
        break;
    }
}

function generarNumRandom(){
    var numRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (17 - 9 + 1) + 9);  
    if (numRandom == 13) {
        var numRandom2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (17 - 9 + 1) + 9);  
        return numRandom2;
    } else {
        return numRandom; 
    }
}

function pintaMaquina (){
    maquina = "o";
    alert("Esta pintando la maquina...");

    var numRandom = generarNumRandom();
    alert("numRandom " + numRandom );
    
        if (GuardarPosiciones.includes("-",numRandom)) { //Si en la posicion del numero random hay una - pintamos encima
            alert("no existe ningun valor");
            pintarO(numRandom);
            GuardarPosiciones.splice(numRandom,0,maquina);
            alert(GuardarPosiciones);
        } else {
            alert("Si que existe un valor");
            pintaMaquina();
        } 

}

function GanaMaquina() {
    //Todas las casillas
    let oP9 = n1.includes("o");
    let oP10 = n2.includes("o");
    let oP11 = n3.includes("o");

    let oP12 = n4.includes("o");
    let oP13 = n5.includes("o");
    let oP14 = n6.includes("o");

    let oP15 = n7.includes("o");
    let oP16 = n8.includes("o");
    let oP17 = n9.includes("o");

    if (oP9 && oP10 && oP11) {
        //primera fila horizontal
        return true;

    } else if (oP12 && oP13 && oP14) {
        //segunda fila horizontal
        return true;

    } else if (oP15 && oP16 && oP17) {
        //tercera fila horizontal
        return true;

    } else if (oP9 && oP12 && oP15) {
        //primera fila vertical
        return true;

    } else if (oP10 && oP13 && oP16) {
        //segunda fila vertical
        return true;

    } else if (oP11 && oP14 && oP17) {
        //tercera fila vertical
        return true;

    } else if (oP9 && oP13 && oP17) {
        //primera fila diagonal
        return true;

    } else if (oP11 && oP13 && oP15) {
        //segunda fila diagonal
        return true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function GanaJugador() {
    //Todas las casillas
    let xP9 = n1.includes("x");
    let xP10 = n2.includes("x");
    let xP11 = n3.includes("x");

    let xP12 = n4.includes("x");
    let xP14 = n6.includes("x");

    let xP15 = n7.includes("x");
    let xP16 = n8.includes("x");
    let xP17 = n9.includes("x");

    if (xP9 && xP10 && xP11) {
        //primera fila horizontal
        return true;

    } else if (xP15 && xP16 && xP17) {
        //tercera fila horizontal
        return true;

    } else if (xP9 && xP12 && xP15) {
        //primera fila vertical
        return true;

    } else if (xP11 && xP14 && xP17) {
        //tercera fila vertical
        return true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function condicionesGanaroPerder(){
    //Condiciones de ganar, perder o empate
    if (GanaMaquina()) {
        alert("La máquina ha ganado")
        location.reload();
        
    } else if (GanaJugador()) {
        alert("¡El jugador ha ganado!")
        location.reload();

    } else if (!GuardarPosiciones.length)  {
        //Hasta que el array no se llene no habrá empate
        alert("Empate");
        location.reload();
    } else {
        //Aún no gana
        pintaMaquina();
    }
}
```

```html
    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Juego 3 en raya</title>

    <script src="./Funcionamiento.js">
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .respuestas { 
            font-weight: bolder;
            color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
            text-transform: uppercase;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <form action="Funcionamiento.js">
    <input type="text" class="respuestas" id="casilla1" onFocus="vaciarTexto(this),desactivarCasillas(this)" name="c" value="-" style="width:25px;height:30px;background-color:#CBCBCB"></input>
    <input type="text" class="respuestas" id="casilla2" onFocus="vaciarTexto(this),desactivarCasillas(this)" name="c" value="-" style="width:25px;height:30px;background-color:#CBCBCB"></input>
    <input type="text" class="respuestas" id="casilla3" onFocus="vaciarTexto(this),desactivarCasillas(this)" name="c" value="-" style="width:25px;height:30px;background-color:#CBCBCB"></input>

    <br>
    
    <input type="text" class="respuestas" id="casilla4" onFocus="vaciarTexto(this),desactivarCasillas(this)" name="c" value="-" style="width:25px;height:30px;background-color:#CBCBCB"></input>
    <input type="text" class="respuestas" disabled id="casilla5" value="o" style="width:25px;height:30px;align-content:center;background-color:#00BDFF"></input>
    <input type="text" class="respuestas" id="casilla6" onFocus="vaciarTexto(this),desactivarCasillas(this)" name="c" value="-" style="width:25px;height:30px;background-color:#CBCBCB"></input>

    <br>

    <input type="text" class="respuestas" id="casilla7" onFocus="vaciarTexto(this),desactivarCasillas(this)" name="c" value="-" style="width:25px;height:30px;background-color:#CBCBCB"></input>
    <input type="text" class="respuestas" id="casilla8" onFocus="vaciarTexto(this),desactivarCasillas(this)" name="c" value="-" style="width:25px;height:30px;background-color:#CBCBCB"></input>
    <input type="text" class="respuestas" id="casilla9" onFocus="vaciarTexto(this),desactivarCasillas(this)" name="c" value="-" style="width:25px;height:30px;background-color:#CBCBCB"></input>
    </form>

    <br>
    <br>

    <input type="button" value="   Fin del turno  "  onclick="activarCasillas(),ingresar_datos(),condicionesGanaroPerder()"></input>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿No crees que es buena idea usar ciclos? Esa y algunos otros cambios simplificaría bastante tu código además de mejorar su legibilidad.

Comment: Lo he intentado pero no me aclaro y todo me da errores así que... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema ya lo mencionó Alan. Pero quería mostrarte como puedes reducir el código.

Si prestas atención, puedes poner todas las casillas en un arreglo y mediante un for hacer la misma acción repetitiva con menos código.

Como `GanaJugador` y `GanaMaquina` son iguales y solo cambia la letra que usa, puedes deshacerte de una e introducir un parámetro que determine la letra.

Verás que uso el operador `...` que expresa el resultado de `document.getElementsByClassName("respuestas")` como `elemento1, elemento2, elemento3, etc`. Para convertir el `HTMLCollection` en un arreglo que es más práctico.

También uso [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (crea un nuevo array con los resultados de la llamada a la función indicada aplicados a cada uno de sus elementos) en reemplazo de este fragmento:

```
let oP9 = n1.includes("o");
let oP10 = n2.includes("o");
let oP11 = n3.includes("o");

let oP12 = n4.includes("o");
let oP13 = n5.includes("o");
let oP14 = n6.includes("o");

let oP15 = n7.includes("o");
let oP16 = n8.includes("o");
let oP17 = n9.includes("o");
```

Entre otras cosas, modifiqué `pintaMaquina` para que elija una casilla de las disponibles.

```js
// Pone todas las casillas en un arreglo
var casillas = [...document.getElementsByClassName("respuestas")];

// Activa todas las casillas con un -
function activarCasillas(){
    for (const casilla of casillas) {
        if (casilla.value === "-")
            casilla.disabled = false;
    }  
}

// Desactiva todas las casillas
function desactivarCasillas(){
    for (const casilla of casillas) {
        casilla.disabled = true;
    }  
}

function pintarO(i){
    // Ponemos una o en el numero random que elija la máquina
    if (i >= 0 && i < casillas.length){
        casillas[i].classList.add("O");
        casillas[i].value = "O";
        casillas[i].disabled = true;
    }
}

function pintaMaquina(){
    maquina = "o";
    alert("Esta pintando la maquina...");

    var casillasDisponibles = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < casillas.length; i++){
        if (casillas[i].value === "-")
            casillasDisponibles.push(i);
    }
    var rng = Math.round(Math.random() * (casillasDisponibles.length - 1))
    var numRandom = casillasDisponibles[rng];

    pintarO(numRandom);
}

function Gana(letra) {
    //Todas las casillas

    let checks = casillas.map(pos => pos.value === letra)

    // Filas 
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i += 3) {
        if (checks[i] && checks[i + 1] && checks[i + 2])
            return true
    }

    // Columnas
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (checks[i] && checks[i + 3] && checks[i + 6])
            return true
    }

    // Diagonales
    if (checks[0] && checks[4] && checks[8])
        return true;
    
    if (checks[2] && checks[4] && checks[6])
        return true;

    return false;
}

function condicionesGanaroPerder(){
    //Condiciones de ganar, perder o empate
    if (Gana("O")) {
        alert("La máquina ha ganado")
        
    } else if (Gana("X")) {
        alert("¡El jugador ha ganado!")

    } else if (casillas.every(casilla => casilla.value !== "-"))  {
        //Hasta que el array no se llene no habrá empate
        alert("Empate");
    } else {
        //Aún no gana
        pintaMaquina();
        if (Gana("O")) {
            alert("La máquina ha ganado")
        }
    }
}

function clickCasilla(i) {
    casillas[i].classList.add("X");
    casillas[i].value = "X";
    casillas[i].disabled = true;

    desactivarCasillas()
}
```

```css
.respuestas {
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #CBCBCB;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}

.respuestas.O {
    background: #00BDFF;
}

.respuestas.X {
    background: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Juego 3 en raya</title>

    <script src="./Funcionamiento.js">
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <form action="Funcionamiento.js">
    <input type="button" class="respuestas" id="casilla1" onclick="clickCasilla(0)" name="c" value="-"></input>
    <input type="button" class="respuestas" id="casilla2" onclick="clickCasilla(1)" name="c" value="-"></input>
    <input type="button" class="respuestas" id="casilla3" onclick="clickCasilla(2)" name="c" value="-"></input>

    <br>
    
    <input type="button" class="respuestas" id="casilla4" onclick="clickCasilla(3)" name="c" value="-"></input>
    <input type="button" class="respuestas" id="casilla5" onclick="clickCasilla(4)" name="c" value="-"></input>
    <input type="button" class="respuestas" id="casilla6" onclick="clickCasilla(5)" name="c" value="-"></input>

    <br>

    <input type="button" class="respuestas" id="casilla7" onclick="clickCasilla(6)" name="c" value="-"></input>
    <input type="button" class="respuestas" id="casilla8" onclick="clickCasilla(7)" name="c" value="-"></input>
    <input type="button" class="respuestas" id="casilla9" onclick="clickCasilla(8)" name="c" value="-"></input>
    </form>

    <br>
    <br>

    <input type="button" value="   Fin del turno  "  onclick="condicionesGanaroPerder(); activarCasillas()"></input>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Mateo! estoy mirándolo paso por paso porque aún estoy muy verde en esto de Javascript, está mucho mejor optimizado y se entiende super bien el código

Answer (score 3):

Tu problema esta en esta linea:

```
if (GuardarPosiciones.includes("-",numRandom)) {
```

No puedes usar `includes` porque esa funcion busca en todo el array.  Necesitas comparar la posicion exacta.  Ademas tambien necesitas comparar si esa posicion ya esta ocupada por el otro jugador.  Quedaria asi:

```js
const GuardarPosiciones = new Array(9);
var n1 = "-";
var n2 = "-";
var n3 = "-";
var n4 = "-";
var n5 = "o";
var n6 = "-";
var n7 = "-";
var n8 = "-";
var n9 = "-";
var agregarPosiciones;

function vaciarTexto(){
    //Al clicar se pone automaticamente una x y se cambia el fondo en rojo
    var selected = document.activeElement;

    if (selected.id == "casilla1") {
        document.getElementById("casilla1").value ="x";
        document.getElementById("casilla1").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
        document.getElementById("casilla1").disabled = true;
    } else if (selected.id == "casilla2") {
        document.getElementById("casilla2").value ="x";  
        document.getElementById("casilla2").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
        document.getElementById("casilla2").disabled = true;
    } else if (selected.id == "casilla3") {
        document.getElementById("casilla3").value ="x";
        document.getElementById("casilla3").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
        document.getElementById("casilla3").disabled = true;
    } else if (selected.id == "casilla4") {
        document.getElementById("casilla4").value ="x";  
        document.getElementById("casilla4").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
        document.getElementById("casilla4").disabled = true;
    } else if (selected.id == "casilla5") {
        document.getElementById("casilla5").value ="x";
        document.getElementById("casilla5").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
        document.getElementById("casilla5").disabled = true;
    } else if (selected.id == "casilla6") {
        document.getElementById("casilla6").value ="x";  
        document.getElementById("casilla6").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
        document.getElementById("casilla6").disabled = true;
    } else if (selected.id == "casilla7") {
        document.getElementById("casilla7").value ="x";
        document.getElementById("casilla7").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
        document.getElementById("casilla7").disabled = true;
    } else if (selected.id == "casilla8") {
        document.getElementById("casilla8").value ="x";  
        document.getElementById("casilla8").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
        document.getElementById("casilla8").disabled = true;
    } else if (selected.id == "casilla9") {
        document.getElementById("casilla9").value ="x";
        document.getElementById("casilla9").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
        document.getElementById("casilla9").disabled = true;
    } 

}

function desactivarCasillas(){
    //desabilitamos todas las casillas al usuario meter una x
    document.getElementById("casilla1").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("casilla2").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("casilla3").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("casilla4").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("casilla5").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("casilla6").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("casilla7").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("casilla8").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("casilla9").disabled = true;     
}

function activarCasillas(){
    //habilitamos todas las casillas al inicio
    document.getElementById("casilla1").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("casilla2").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("casilla3").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("casilla4").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("casilla5").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("casilla6").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("casilla7").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("casilla8").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("casilla9").disabled = false;     
}

function ingresar_datos() {
    //ingresamos los datos recogidos después de habilitar las casillas
    n1 = document.getElementById('casilla1').value;
    n2 = document.getElementById('casilla2').value;
    n3 = document.getElementById('casilla3').value;
    n4 = document.getElementById('casilla4').value;
    n5 = document.getElementById('casilla5').value;
    n6 = document.getElementById('casilla6').value;
    n7 = document.getElementById('casilla7').value;
    n8 = document.getElementById('casilla8').value;
    n9 = document.getElementById('casilla9').value;
    agregarPosiciones = GuardarPosiciones.push(n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9);
    console.table(GuardarPosiciones);
}

function pintarO(casilla){
    //ponemos una o en el numero random que elija la máquina
    switch (casilla) {
        case 9:
        casilla1.value ="o";
        casilla1.style.backgroundColor = "#00BDFF";
        document.getElementById("casilla1").disabled = true;
        break;

        case 10:
        casilla2.value ="o";  
        casilla2.style.backgroundColor = "#00BDFF";
        document.getElementById("casilla2").disabled = true;
        break;

        case 11:
        casilla3.value ="o";
        casilla3.style.backgroundColor = "#00BDFF";
        document.getElementById("casilla3").disabled = true;
        break;

        case 12:
        casilla4.value ="o";  
        casilla4.style.backgroundColor = "#00BDFF";
        document.getElementById("casilla4").disabled = true;
        break;

        case 13:
        casilla5.value ="o";
        casilla5.style.backgroundColor = "#00BDFF";
        document.getElementById("casilla5").disabled = true;
        break;

        case 14:
        casilla6.value ="o";  
        casilla6.style.backgroundColor = "#00BDFF";
        document.getElementById("casilla6").disabled = true;
        break;

        case 15:
        casilla7.value ="o";
        casilla7.style.backgroundColor = "#00BDFF";
        document.getElementById("casilla7").disabled = true;
        break;

        case 16:
        casilla8.value ="o";  
        casilla8.style.backgroundColor = "#00BDFF";
        document.getElementById("casilla8").disabled = true;
        break;

        case 17:
        casilla9.value ="o";
        casilla9.style.backgroundColor = "#00BDFF";
        document.getElementById("casilla9").disabled = true;
        break;
    }
}

function generarNumRandom(){
    var numRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (17 - 9 + 1) + 9);  
    if (numRandom == 13) {
        var numRandom2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (17 - 9 + 1) + 9);  
        return numRandom2;
    } else {
        return numRandom; 
    }
}

function pintaMaquina (){
    maquina = "o";
    alert("Esta pintando la maquina...");

    var numRandom = generarNumRandom();
    alert("numRandom " + numRandom );
    
        if (GuardarPosiciones[numRandom] == "-") { //Si en la posicion del numero random hay una - pintamos encima
            alert("no existe ningun valor");
            pintarO(numRandom);
            GuardarPosiciones.splice(numRandom,0,maquina);
            alert(GuardarPosiciones);
        } else {
            alert("Si que existe un valor");
            pintaMaquina();
        } 

}

function GanaMaquina() {
    //Todas las casillas
    let oP9 = n1.includes("o");
    let oP10 = n2.includes("o");
    let oP11 = n3.includes("o");

    let oP12 = n4.includes("o");
    let oP13 = n5.includes("o");
    let oP14 = n6.includes("o");

    let oP15 = n7.includes("o");
    let oP16 = n8.includes("o");
    let oP17 = n9.includes("o");

    if (oP9 && oP10 && oP11) {
        //primera fila horizontal
        return true;

    } else if (oP12 && oP13 && oP14) {
        //segunda fila horizontal
        return true;

    } else if (oP15 && oP16 && oP17) {
        //tercera fila horizontal
        return true;

    } else if (oP9 && oP12 && oP15) {
        //primera fila vertical
        return true;

    } else if (oP10 && oP13 && oP16) {
        //segunda fila vertical
        return true;

    } else if (oP11 && oP14 && oP17) {
        //tercera fila vertical
        return true;

    } else if (oP9 && oP13 && oP17) {
        //primera fila diagonal
        return true;

    } else if (oP11 && oP13 && oP15) {
        //segunda fila diagonal
        return true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function GanaJugador() {
    //Todas las casillas
    let xP9 = n1.includes("x");
    let xP10 = n2.includes("x");
    let xP11 = n3.includes("x");

    let xP12 = n4.includes("x");
    let xP14 = n6.includes("x");

    let xP15 = n7.includes("x");
    let xP16 = n8.includes("x");
    let xP17 = n9.includes("x");

    if (xP9 && xP10 && xP11) {
        //primera fila horizontal
        return true;

    } else if (xP15 && xP16 && xP17) {
        //tercera fila horizontal
        return true;

    } else if (xP9 && xP12 && xP15) {
        //primera fila vertical
        return true;

    } else if (xP11 && xP14 && xP17) {
        //tercera fila vertical
        return true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function condicionesGanaroPerder(){
    //Condiciones de ganar, perder o empate
    if (GanaMaquina()) {
        alert("La máquina ha ganado")
        location.reload();
        
    } else if (GanaJugador()) {
        alert("¡El jugador ha ganado!")
        location.reload();

    } else if (!GuardarPosiciones.length)  {
        //Hasta que el array no se llene no habrá empate
        alert("Empate");
        location.reload();
    } else {
        //Aún no gana
        pintaMaquina();
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Juego 3 en raya</title>

    <script src="./Funcionamiento.js">
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .respuestas { 
            font-weight: bolder;
            color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
            text-transform: uppercase;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <form action="Funcionamiento.js">
    <input type="text" class="respuestas" id="casilla1" onFocus="vaciarTexto(this),desactivarCasillas(this)" name="c" value="-" style="width:25px;height:30px;background-color:#CBCBCB"></input>
    <input type="text" class="respuestas" id="casilla2" onFocus="vaciarTexto(this),desactivarCasillas(this)" name="c" value="-" style="width:25px;height:30px;background-color:#CBCBCB"></input>
    <input type="text" class="respuestas" id="casilla3" onFocus="vaciarTexto(this),desactivarCasillas(this)" name="c" value="-" style="width:25px;height:30px;background-color:#CBCBCB"></input>

    <br>
    
    <input type="text" class="respuestas" id="casilla4" onFocus="vaciarTexto(this),desactivarCasillas(this)" name="c" value="-" style="width:25px;height:30px;background-color:#CBCBCB"></input>
    <input type="text" class="respuestas" disabled id="casilla5" value="o" style="width:25px;height:30px;align-content:center;background-color:#00BDFF"></input>
    <input type="text" class="respuestas" id="casilla6" onFocus="vaciarTexto(this),desactivarCasillas(this)" name="c" value="-" style="width:25px;height:30px;background-color:#CBCBCB"></input>

    <br>

    <input type="text" class="respuestas" id="casilla7" onFocus="vaciarTexto(this),desactivarCasillas(this)" name="c" value="-" style="width:25px;height:30px;background-color:#CBCBCB"></input>
    <input type="text" class="respuestas" id="casilla8" onFocus="vaciarTexto(this),desactivarCasillas(this)" name="c" value="-" style="width:25px;height:30px;background-color:#CBCBCB"></input>
    <input type="text" class="respuestas" id="casilla9" onFocus="vaciarTexto(this),desactivarCasillas(this)" name="c" value="-" style="width:25px;height:30px;background-color:#CBCBCB"></input>
    </form>

    <br>
    <br>

    <input type="button" value="   Fin del turno  "  onclick="activarCasillas(),ingresar_datos(),condicionesGanaroPerder()"></input>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias llevaba días con este error :D

Comment: Sigue machacando la X la máquina

Comment: Tienes razon, no necesitas comparar si hay x o no, ya edite mi respuesta